# Can you simplify a expression with an exponent that is divided by a number?

Tags: divisibility, exponentiation

As the title suggests, I have 
    $\;a^{(b/c)}.$

Is there any way to simplify this so that there is no dividing in the exponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it as $\sqrt[c]{a^b}=\sqrt[c]{a}^b=(a^{\frac{1}{c}})^b=a^{b/c}$.  There isn't really any other way to simplify it, unless there's some context to your question.

Comment: ahh...So we just need to put \sqrt[c]{something}

Comment: Careful, there's a condition... e.g. $1=((-1)^2)^{1/2}\ne((-1)^{1/2})^2=-1$

Comment: I assumed he was talking about real numbers (I know $-1\in\mathbb{R}$, you know what I mean)

Comment: Both you guys answered my question, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to reduce the fraction, but once so reduced, if still a fraction, then no, unless you express the denominator $c$ as the $c$th root of $a^b$.